# Ubuntu design website duplication

Tags: canonical, websites, ubuntu-website

Why Ubuntu maintaining two website for the same purpose. One is http://design.ubuntu.com and another one is http://design.canonical.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the question should be put as follows: "Why Canonical maintaining two website for the same purpose". As you can check at http://whois.net/, Canonical Ltd is the registrant of both domains, not Ubuntu.

Second, http://design.ubuntu.com is about what is specified [in this section](http://design.ubuntu.com/audiences) and http://design.canonical.com is just a blog about Ubuntu design.